# Creating a Sign Up Page on Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am attempting to create a sign up page for my android application using Java. I have created the class and I currently get 0 errors when I build. I input the details and press sign up. Although it says sign up successful, the relevant information is not added to my firebase DB. Any suggestions? Thanks.

CODE:

```
package myapp.zeeee.partyloader;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

import myapp.zeeee.partyloader.model.User;

public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

MaterialEditText editPhoneNo,editName,editPassword;
Button signUpBtn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    editName = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    editPassword = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.editPassword);
    editPhoneNo = (MaterialEditText)findViewById(R.id.editPhoneNo);

    signUpBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);

    //Init Firebase
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference table_user = 
          database.getReference("User");

    signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ProgressDialog mDialog = 
               new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
            mDialog .setMessage("loading...");
            mDialog.show();

            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener()
             {

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot 
             dataSnapshot) {
                    //Check to see if the phone no. is already used

if(dataSnapshot.child(editPhoneNo.getText().toString()).exists())
                    {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Phone Number 
                       already in use", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mDialog.dismiss();
                        User User = new  
User(editName.getText().toString(),editPassword.getText().toString());

table_user.child(editPhoneNo.getText().toString()).setValue(User);

                       Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Sign Up 
                       Successful!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError 
databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

}

[Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLNnI.png)

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Hi, I have now added it to the end of the code above, thanks.

Comment: So that data was added manually, right?

Comment: yes, this data was manually added to the .json file and uploaded to firebase.

Comment: Is any of those Toast messages displayed?

Comment: Yes they are all displayed. It just does not add the data to the DB.

Comment: Do you have the correct permissions?

Comment: The Database rules?

Comment: Yes, are those rules set correctly?

Comment: yes they are set.